# Is there a way to manually increment a pk in DynamoDB using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to write a function that will insert data into my DynamoDB using boto3. I am trying to find the largest ID in the DB and increment it by one in order to give that to my inserted object making it the latest ID. I know that DynamoDB does not support auto-increment and that most would suggest using a UUID however that would require me to restructure my tables and I would like to avoid that if possible. Is there any way to find the largest number of an attribute so I could increment it manually for my insertion?

I have tried to use the describe_table function to get the item count however that only updates every 6 hours which does not work well for my use-case. I have also tried the following block of code, but I just found it online and it throws an error stating that the provided key element does not match the schema.

```
response = table.update_item(
    Key={'pk': 'transaction_id'},
    UpdateExpression="ADD #cnt :val",
    ExpressionAttributeNames={'#cnt': 'count'},
    ExpressionAttributeValues={':val': 1},
    ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
)
```

Comment: If you were to re-design the schema, you might prefer ULID over UUID for sorting.

Comment: Aside from the table definition change proposed by Leroy, the only way to determine the highest value is to scan the table. That won't work well, of course, because someone else could insert an item while you're scanning.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you don't require much scale? For that reason I would suggest that you use a static partition key value, and what you use as partition key now should be the sort key.

Both of these blogs combined will provide you the solution to your question:

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/effective-data-sorting-with-amazon-dynamodb/
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implement-auto-increment-with-amazon-dynamodb/

The alternative approach is to use transactions, every time you add an item you update a counter item to keep count of the current partition key value. Transactions will increase your write throughput consumption, instead of 1 WCU, you will increase it to 4 WCU as you need to write with transactions to two items.